# Why does journalctl say "-- no entries --"?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, syslog, systemd-journald, journalctl

For example:

```
┌─[10:50:38/hypership/root/~]
└─╼ journalctl -b
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --

┌─[10:50:46/hypership/root/~]
└─╼ journalctl --verify
No journal files were found.
```

`/var/log` is full of files though, and this was working before. Seems like an Arch Linux update may have caused this.

Any idea what the problem may be? What more info can I provide?

Comment: journalctl -k shows dmesg (kernel messages), you can get the same output by simple running the command "dmesg". To check if journalctl is working for non-kernel messages just type journalctl -b, if that doesn't give any logs then paste the output of systemctl status systemd-journald*

Comment: art thou root??

Comment: @HeshamAhmed Updated my output to show output from -b and --verify options.

Comment: @PeterTurner Yeah, I'm root.

Comment: journalctl doesn't read normal log files but journal files in /var/log/journal/<uniquehash> folder. Can you check this folder exists and has .journal files in it? If not you just have to restart journald service so it can recreate the whole thing. To restart journald run `systemctl restart systemd-journald.service`

Comment: @HeshamAhmed `systemctl status` shows systemd-journald.service was "active" while this was happening. Restarting the service seems to have fixed it. Let me see if other apps start logging again...

Comment: You could also get this error message, if you query logs for a specific service, and just made a typo in the service name, as I just did.

Answer (score 26):

1. `sudo -i` if not already.
2. Try running `journalctl -b` to see messages from the current boot.
3. If you still get `-- No entries --`, run `journalctl --verify`.
4. If you get `No journal files were found`, something is corrupted with the journal service itself. Run `systemctl status systemd-journald*`
5. If the services are all "green" (active/running), something is borked with the log files in `/var/log/journal/<hash>`. Try running the following to recreate them:

`systemctl restart systemd-journald.service`

The previous command will restart `journald` with a new hash under `/var/log/journal`. Now if you run `journalctl -b` you should see messages about the service itself starting.

Unfortunately the files under `/var/log/journal` are not parseable so figuring out the initial problem may be difficult, but at least logs going forward will work again.

Comment: after `systemctl restart systemd-journald.service` everything worked fine!

Comment: `systemctl restart systemd-journald.service` worked perfectly. I had a fresh droplet created on DO which ships with `systemd 245` version (Ubuntu 18.04) but all journal entries were missing.

Comment: on `journalctl --verify` I got 1 failure, but magically after that it all started working just fine :)