# Why does journalctl --user asks for password and says “— no entries --”?

Tags: journalctl

I'm trying to find why one of my Systemd user units is failing. This unit is stored in /etc/systemd/user (I know I can also put it in .config/systemd/user) and fails to start.

I tried to run `journalctl --user -u my_unit`, but after asking for my password, I get this answer:

```
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

First, why do I have to provide a password? I'm using the `--user` argument, I should be able to use it without password (I can for instance do `systemctl --user start my_unit` with no password).

Looking at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538881), I tried `journalctl --verify` and it works. `journalctl --user --verify` still returns `No journal files were found.`.

Is there something special to configure for jounarlctl to properly log user units?